# insert COUNT n1 and n2 column in SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with item_name and item_color.
Trying to make a data grid where, i want to show list of items with the total count of items and the split count based on its other properties like color as result rows.

For Example,

I have 10 chairs in table so item_name='chair' should give three rows as mentioned below.

```
Item_name  Item_color  quantity
    Chair         ALL       10
    Chair         Red        5
    Chair         Black      5
```

Could anybody give me some idea where should i start from?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using UNION ALL and then aggregate function COUNT() with GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT item_name, 'ALL', COUNT(*)  as Quantity
FROM tbl
GROUP BY item_name
UNION ALL 
SELECT item_name, item_color, COUNT(*) as Quantity
FROM tbl
GROUP BY item_name, item_color
```

Comment: You're welcome @MBP. Glad it work for you. Happy coding and GOD bless.